# Brisker Shiurim Online

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, torah-study, internet, brisk

I am looking for advanced Shiurim online which teach Gemara in the Brisker fashion, does anyone know if any (preferably free) classes are available online?

Comment: Wouldn't any shiur of the Rav suffice for this? Or do you specifically mean from the Brisker rosh yeshivos?

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to try the shiurim of R. Mayer Twersky or R. Michael Rosensweig on http://yutorah.org.

Answer (score 2):

See also the shiurim by R' Aharon Soloveitchik on yutorah.org.

Answer (score 0):

Try the series *[Talmudic Methodology](http://vbm-torah.org/metho.htm)* by R' Moshe Taragin at the [Virtual Beit Midrash](http://vbm-Torah.org).